# How to select duplicate categories except one in a group from database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have an application where I need to select all duplicate categories inside EAN group. See picture below to understand what is going on.

I've tried many approaches as of today I wasn't able to solve the problem. What I got so fat is a list of products grouped by EAN and ordered by ean also each new group row is visualized in different color to better distinguish in between.

I have to admit I am missing the logic here, what I need is a list of product id-s to be able to mark them for deletion but they need to be selected based on this: EAN group > category needs to be appear at least 2 times in the EAN group. The result would a list of product id-s.

I have attached a picture to this question where I marked with green color those I need except the one marked with red.

I was using this code to select those rows, but it selects only one row out or 2 as seen on the picture below

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM products 
GROUP BY ean, categories 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND (MAX(CAST(price as decimal)) OR LENGTH(description) < 100)
```

[image: Application GUI with example rows grouped by EAN]

Comment: Edit your question.  (1) Tag with the database you are really using.  MySQL and SQLite are not the same.  (2) Show the results you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What is a "product id"?  It is not in your sample data.

Comment: Product id is a unique number, it identifiers a single product.

Comment: What is the output that you want? (SQLite cannot draw circles.)

Comment: The desired output would look like something like this https://imgur.com/a/jASPt seen on this picture. 000012345618 there is 2 out of 3 category (1235) marked, 023942433521 there is 1 out of 2 category (157) marked etc. I do not need those circles they there purely for visualization purposes.

Comment: I got it working as required by this way https://pastebin.com/9kCGPV1Y if somebody would need it feel free to use it. But if somebody could found a purely sql version I would glad to hear. Thank you all the participants, you guys are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
Select * from products group by EAN having count(EAN)>1
```

Comment: Indeed something like this `select product_id from products group by ean, categories having count(categories) > 1` works, downside it only selects one occurrence.

Comment: Store that one Category / EAN then use it to delete or update it like 

`Delete from products where EAN in (select EAN from products group by ean, categories having count(categories) > 1`)

Comment: This could work, but the end result is inconsistent. It almost does what I want to achieve on those rows marked on picture. To those should be marked duplicate remains unmarked. It is really disappointing for me that on simple thing like this make such a huge problem.

Comment: What is inconsistent behaviour?


I guess you have to keep one original record and delete other duplicates ,am i right ?

Comment: The only was I can show the end result is visible on this picture: https://imgur.com/a/gNMjn